# Retrieving data from GET request with Cypress, getting undefined error

Tags: javascript, json, api, response, cypress

I'm working on an automated API test framework using Cypress for a medical project. The issue that I'm having is that I cannot retrieve information from the response body. I've done the same thing with another response, but for some reason with this query does not work when I'm making this request.

This is what the top of the Json looks like:

```
 "request": {
  "body": {
   "_embedded": {
    "optometryDrugList": [
     {
      "id": 2887,
     },
     {
      "id": 2888,
     }
```

I've posted a request with 5 different medicines, so there should be 5 optometryDrugListId's. When I the use the following request chain to GET and PUT one of these medicines, I get an "Cannot read property 'optometryDrugList' of undefined" error.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('putOptometryDrugExam', (optometryId, drugName, time, requestStatus) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/' + `optometry-drug?optometryId=${optometryId}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': token,
      'apiKey': 'test'
    }
  })
    .then((request) => {
      const requestBody = request.body
      const optometryDrugId = requestBody._embedded.optometryDrugList[4].id
      return optometryDrugId
    })
    .then((optometryDrugId) => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/' + `optometry-drug/${optometryDrugId}`,
```

So my question now is: what am I doing wrong/not seeing, so that I can get the specific drug ID and use it in the next PUT request? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that it's unable to access the `optometryDrugList` array.

Try using the square brackets property accessor instead of dot property accessor.

And also could you try putting the second PUT request on one `.then` rather than a separate one?

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('putOptometryDrugExam', (optometryId, drugName, time, requestStatus) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/' + `optometry-drug?optometryId=${optometryId}`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': token,
      'apiKey': 'test'
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      const optometryDrugList = request.body._embedded['optometryDrugList'];
      const optometryDrugId = optometryDrugList[4].id;
      
      cy.request({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/' + `optometry-drug/${optometryDrugId}`,
        ...
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give it a try right away!